# Akka disable logging to sysout

Tags: scala, logging, slf4j, akka, logback

Our application uses akka actors (v. 1.1.2) that throw exception from time to time. We would like to have those exceptions logged and are using `event-handlers = ["akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jEventHandler"]` to turn on the logging using slf4j/logback.

However, error log messages are still also written to stdout.

Is there any setting in akka how to disable `EventHandler$DefaultListener` which seems to cause that behavior?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Thanks, Viktor. Finally we have discovered that another akka.conf has been loaded on classpath and it overwritten the settings of logging.

Comment: There's a setting for outputting what config that is loaded. Happy hAkking!

Comment: The key was that the file is named the same so I thought it was the right one.. pretty hard to find one. Thanks for support.